# Java scanner class won't take double

Tags: java

Trying to read keyboard input, but allow for decimals.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TemperaturFormel {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);
//      double temperatur, vindstyrka;
        double temperatur = userIn.nextDouble();
        double vindstyrka = userIn.nextDouble();

        System.out.print(temperatur + "\n" + vindstyrka);
    }

}
```

I tried both with and without declaring the variables as doubles first. It works fine when reading integers, but doubles give InputMismatchException error.

Comment: Have you tried with both `,` and `.` as delimiter?

Comment: and which value did you enter?

Comment: as long as i can remember it was , in windows and . in linux

Comment: the code you posted working fine for me? post the code which gave you exception, post your input too...

Comment: I would've +1'd had you shown the input you supplied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably a locale issue. (Impossible to know for sure, though, since you didn't supply any sample input. It would also help to know your default locale.) You can set the locale that the scanner should use by calling [`Scanner.useLocale(Locale locale)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useLocale%28java.util.Locale%29). See the discussion on "Localized Numbers" in the [`Scanner` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: Yep that was it, my machine was set to use commas for decimal delimiting. Thank you!